# Could not execute Ajax query on new server

Tags: php, ajax, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a simple Ajax query in my HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
       url: "rnd.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

And the function rnd.php is below. This is just an example, to be modified for more complex applications.

```
<?php
$res = (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();
echo "$res"
?>
```

It worked on a previous AWS server, but when I try to configure a new one, Ajax returns the content of the PHP file (on the Chrome debug console) instead of executing it.

Comment: that's because you are telling ajax to do that ! `console.log(data);` will send the output to the console log

Answer (score 0):

I have searched many forums for answers and created 3 new servers on AWS. I could not find the answer anywhere. I ended up using this configuration for Ubuntu (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04). What I think made the difference was that the server name need to be set up properly in the Apache configuration file or the Ajax call will not work even though PHP works. I have added the following line at the end of my apache configuration file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf in Ubuntu)

```
ServerName server_domain_or_IP
```

I have tried with the public IP myself. Then I restarted the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Note that, if using Chrome on the client side, quitting Chrome is not enough and that you need to clear the cache. I was puzzled for 10 minutes why it now worked in Safari but not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have anything to do with the actual ServerName in the conf file, although you'd obviously need to make sure that it was configured properly so you could access it.

What you need to do is make sure that you have the PHP / Apache2 module installed and enabled on your server. So for example, if I'm running Apache2 and PHP 5.6 I would install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: The EC2 instance was originally not on an Elastic (static) IP. It worked. Then I moved it to an elastic IP and it stopped working. I then changed the ServerName to match the Elastic IP one and it worked again. It might all be coincidental and the fact that Chrome cache was not cleared at some point but still.